# Comandos MySQL no Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

estou tentando fazer uma rotina para deploy de uma aplicação, e me deparei com um problema no shell script, os comando relativos a mysql não consigo executar dentro do mesmo, porem no prompt funcionam, o que deve ser feito?

```
mysql -u sdesk_autoinstall -pSENHA;
CREATE DATABASE $1;
echo "Database $1 created"
CREATE USER '$1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$2';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $1 . * TO '$1'@'localhost';
echo "User permission inserted"
use $1;
source /var/www/app.dominio.com/install/db/db_demo.sql;
mkdir /var/www/app.dominio.com.br/html/$1
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode tentar da seguinte forma:

```
mysql -u USUARIO -pSENHA NOMEBANCO -e "QUERY QUE VOCÊ QUER EXECUTAR NO MYSQL"
```

ex:

```
mysql -u user -psenha  mysql -e "select * from user;"
```